# Magento: A 2nd store, 2nd URL in same installation/backend

Tags: magento, dns

how does one setup a Magento store with multiple stores? I have read many Mage howto's, but it seems I am still missing some basic DNS/hosting information.

Link I used:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

I have setup the case statement en configged te store. But how do I configure all the domains in direct admin? I use pointers now, but what I see is that it creates a loop for domain2. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is used and domain2 points to website1.

QUESTION: How do I setup the 2 domains prior to the whole Magento config in direct admin? (for this method to work)

Thanks, Sean

Comment: After some research: it now seems directadmin is not setting the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variabele correctly and hence Mage cannot detect the store in the switch/case statement. Anyone any experience when and how this can occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Domain pointer in directadmin should be set with the ALIAS box CHECKED

Then wait some time for it to update to he server (maybe waiting was the trick when we were debugging all options)

A good method is to make a filw with phpinfo() in te root and lookup the value of HTTP_HOST there. It will tell you quick enough what is happening